# Does the sequence $f\chi_{E_n^c}$ converge pointwise to $f$ if the measure of $E_n$ tends to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space, $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are such that $f\geq 0$ and $E_n\subseteq X$ measureable are such that $\mu(E_n)\rightarrow 0$, how would I be able to show that $f_n\equiv f\chi_{E_n^c}$ converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$?

Comment: That condition wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$E_1 = [0, 1/2]$; $E_2 = [1/2, 1]$

$E_3 = [0,1/4]$; $E_4 = [1/4,1/2]$; $E_5 = [1/2,3/4]$; $E_6 = [3/4,1]$

$E_7 = [0,1/8]$; $E_8 = [1/8,1/4]$; etc.

Then $\mu(E_n) \rightarrow 0$, but for any $x \in [0,1]$, it's easy to see that $f_n(x) = f(x)\chi_{E_n^c}(x)$ differs from $f(x)$ for infinitely many $n$, so $f_n(x)$ does not converge pointwise to $f(x)$ for any $x \in [0,1]$, except at points where $f(x) = 0$.

---

**Edit** to address the question raised by Cameron Williams: would the result be true if the $E_n$ were nested?

I think this suffices. If the $E_n$ are nested, and $f(x) > 0$, then the condition $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ is equivalent to $x \in \left(\bigcap E_n\right)^c$, and $\mu(\bigcap E_n) = 0$ because $\mu(E_n) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I had something like this in mind. Would nesting of the $E_n$ do it for us?